# Is Bilinear regression a form of Multivariate polynomial regression?

Tags: regression

I came across a similarity/metric learning method that takes in the form of $x^TWy = z$, where $ x $ and $y$ are real valued vectors. For example, two images.

Breaking it into a more familiar form: $ x^TWy = \sum_{ij}w_{ij} x_{i}y_{j} = z $

This essentially looks very similar to polynomial regression with only interactions between features (without the polynomials). i.e. $z = f_w(x)= \sum_{i} w_ix_i +  \sum _i\sum _{j=i+1} w_{ij}x_ix_j$

I was curious to see if the optimization for the matrix W is the same as doing optimization for multivariate linear/polynomial regression, since $x$ and $y$ are fixed, and the only variate is the weight matrix $W$?

And if it is a form of linear regression, is the optimization then convex?

Comment: migration was requested

Answer (score 1):

How your data looks like? 
If you have only one vector $(z, x_1, ..., x_p, y_1, ..., y_p)$ and you want to find matrix $W$ such that $z = x'Wy$, then this is simple linear equation with infinite set of solutions, i.e., infinitely many $ W$s can solve it. If you have $p(p+1)/2$ distinct vectors of that kind, i.e., 
$$
\{(z_i, x_{1i}, ..., x_{pi}, y_{1i}, ..., y_{pi})\}_{i=1}^{p(p+1)/2},
$$ 
then you'll have unique solution (no optimization is required, just inverting matrices in whatever method you like). And if you have more than $p(p+1)/2$ distinct such vectors, then this is a linear regression problem, i.e., 
$$
z_i = \sum_{i\ge j} \beta_{ij}x_iy_j + \epsilon_i,
$$
that you can solve using ordinary least squares, which is indeed convex optimization problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the indices for $\beta xy$ be $\beta_{ijk}x_jy_k$?